# Empty JSON-String with new Object with JavaScript and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, stringify

I'm struggling about the following problem:

```
function(name) {    
    var newfrag = {
        name: name
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(newfrag));
    $.post(this.createURL("fragment"),newfrag,callback);
```

What you can see here are 3 lines of code. They are the only content of the given function. The console.log produces the following output (Independent of the value of name and independent of '' around the key, 'name': name doesn't work either.):

```
{}
```

The server (ExpressJS with Body-Parser) receives and parses the following object:

```
{ '{}': '' }
```

I have absolutely no clue why the object doesn't get send or even converted to a string as expected.

Used frameworks and tools:
Browserify, JQuery, React on Client-Side.
NodeJS, ExpressJS on Server-Side

Comment: Why you use the same name for key and for the parameter? It is confusing and maybe this is the issue.

Comment: Can you show the output of `console.log(newfrag);`. The only reason why `JSON.stringify(newfrag)`  would return `{}` is when the parameter `name` is `undefined`.

Comment: @Konst that won't be a problem.

Comment: Thx, name was undefined and that produced the malformed Object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the first comment below the question.

My mistake was that the name passed to the function was undefined because of a typo. With the correct string passed to the function everything works fine.

Sorry.